# When they make physical locks, do they really just make a few variations of the keys and then mix them together and sell?

Tags: physical, physical-access, locks, padlocks

I always assumed that each lock is unique and can only be opened with the keys it was sold with (or any copies made later from those originals). But the truth seems to be that they just make "a few" variations (10? 100? 1,000? 10,000?), mix them together and sell them, hoping that it will be "secure enough".

Is this really true? I could just buy 100 copies of the same lock product from a store, take out all the keys, put them on a keyring and then try them all until the lock I want to open opens up? If that's true, it crushes my illusion of security that I did have about locks in general.

I assume that, even if the above is true, there must be some kind of expensive, high-end locks which do have unique keys? Can you buy such in normal stores at all?

Comment: If you mean, "I could just buy 100, 1,000, or 10,000 copies of the same lock product from a store and then try them all until the specific lock from that manufacturer opens up?".  Then technically, yes.

Comment: Technically yes, but practically you will be standing in front of that door for a long time.